# Rails undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass and I don't get why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined, rails-activerecord

Hi guys I am developing a system I created on RoR

My idea is that a person can attend to serveral events, So I have 3 tables:
Person, event, and attend

Attend contains person_id event_id I would say that it is a kind of associative table
[image: Person model]

[image]

[image]

I want to show the attendants of a specific event so I in the show action of my controller I  have [image]

And in my view

### [image]

I get the right info in most of the events
[image]

But only in a few this is happening to me 
[image]

and I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT TO DO.

Thanks in advance for your attention and help

Comment: Try adding if attend person at the end of each erb statement. So the first one would be <%= attend.person.name + ' ' + attend.person.last_name if attend.person.present? %>

Comment: Rails will throw an error on an associated attribute like attend.person.name if it is blank otherwise.

Comment: Please post code, errors or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Comment: Even though you can hide the error message by validating the presence of one value of the person (attendee) as the answers shown below with try method, the correct answer for this is that your validations in the models are not working correctly. Since your errors say that the person object is nil from an specific event, you should validate in your Attend model the existance of people for an event and the error will go away since you´re always have people for events. Could be something with validate_presence_of person.

Answer (score 1):

Rails has a built-in helper to handle `nil` values elegantly:

`<%= @attend.person.try(:name) + ' ' + attend.person.try(:last_name) %>`

If `person` is `nil`, it will return `nil` instead of raising a `NoMethodError` exception.

Also, you can concatenate these strings in a more elegant way by taking advantage of string interpolation in Ruby. When you use double quotes, anything in the string wrapped inside `#{}` gets evaluated as Ruby code.

`<%= "#{@attend.person.try(:name)} #{attend.person.try(:last_name)}" %>`